# how to get count of total record

Tags: views, 8, paging

I'm using drupal pagination here i have add some part of my code pagination is working perfect while I'm trying to get the total no of record it is always displaying 10. As i understand i have set the limit 10 so it displaying only total 10

```
$query->orderBy('r.published_date', 'DESC');
        $pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);
    $results = $pager->execute()->fetchAll();
```

This `$results` variable I'm getting data with the set of 10 values.

I would like to display total no of data for that i have created other variable where i have directly executed query in `$result` so it could give total no of records but its not working it displaying only 10

```
$result = $query->execute();
        while($data = $result->fetchObject()){
           $count_ret[]=$data->published_date;
        }
             $total=count($count_ret);
```

please  guide me where i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the issue [Convert pager.inc to a service](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2044435) is solved you find the pager information still in global variables:

```
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items, $pager_limits;

$count_of_total_records = $pager_total_items[$element];
```

Where `$element` defaults to `'0'` if this is the first pager with no element id set.

Comment: Thanks i was using like this  global $pager_total_items;
                                          global $pager_total;
                                            echo $pager_total; echo $pager_total."hiiii";